# Assigning Value to XSLT variable is not working

Tags: xslt

A little strange issue I am facing, When assigning in one line it is working but when in multiple lines it is not working

Working code

---

```
<xsl:variable name="detail" select="utils:DecodeCDATA($addNode2Detail)" />
```

Nonworking code

---

```
<xsl:variable name="detail">

<xsl:valueof select="utils:DecodeCDATA($addNode2Detail)">

</xsl:variable>
```

Please Suggest what can be the reason!!

Comment: Why is it 'not working'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing more, it's very hard to tell. The two variable declarations are NOT equivalent: one binds the variable to a result tree fragment (that is, a document node), while the other binds it to whatever your function utils:DecodeCDATA returns (a string, perhaps?)

You need to tell us more about what the function is doing, more about how you are using the variable, and more about what exactly you mean when you say it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of typos in the line:

```
<xsl:valueof select="utils:DecodeCDATA($addNode2Detail)">
```

try updating it to:

```
<xsl:value-of select="utils:DecodeCDATA($addNode2Detail)"/>
```

Comment: Thanks Jon, any suggestion other than this!!

Comment: If you make these changes your statements should be exactly equivalent I think.

Comment: almost.. if white space is being preserved, there'll be extra white space at the beginning and end of the variable's value. That seems unlikely in this case though.